# Print a line matching pattern1 unless next line contains pattern2

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

I want to match lines that have foo unless the next line contains bar. So given a file containing:

```
1 foo 1 
foo 2
baz bar bap
```

only `1 foo 1` would print.  I got this to work using a negative lookahead `/foo(?!.*\n.*bar)/` on https://regex101.com/r/ZMZsiN/1 but getting this to work on the command line with grep and perl both failed. Any solution using grep or one-liners in perl, sed, awk, or python would be good. Chatgpt failed me.

Some attemps:

```
$grep -Pwe 'foo(?!.*\n.*bar)' testfile
1 foo 1 
foo 2
```

```
$perl -wnl -e  /'foo(?!\n.*bar)/ and print' testfile
1 foo 1 
foo 2
```

```
$perl -ne 'print if /foo/ && ($_ = <>) !~ /bar/' testfile
foo 2
```

The last one is based of something chatgpt gave and is close but my perlfu isn't good enough to figure what's wrong.

Comment: If the last line had `foo` in it, it should also be printed, right, as there is no line after containing `bar`?

Comment: `bar` is last line, shouldn't be printed both first lines???

Comment: @Kusalananda yes correct

Comment: @GillesQuénot No second line should not be printed because the following line contains `bar`.

Comment: Yes, check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` or `perl -n` works on one line at a time so the thing the regexp matches on is just the contents of one line (with the line delimiter not even included with  `grep` or `perl` with `-l`).

You could use `pcregrep` (the `-P` option that GNU `grep` can be built to support uses PCRE as well) which has a multiline mode with `-M`.

```
pcregrep -M '\bfoo\b(?!.*\n.*\bbar\b)'
```

Besides pulling more lines into the subject of the match as needed, the multiline mode in `pcregrep` also enables the `m` flag (implicit `(?m)`) which makes `^` and `$` match at the start and end of each line, not just of the subject and does *not* enabled the `s` flag which means `.` doesn't match newline characters.

(`\b` is for *word `b`oundary*, the `-w` would not put word boundaries in useful places).

With `perl -n`, you could set the record separator to something impossible for the regexp to match on the whole file:

```
perl -0777 -ne '
  print for m{^.*\bfoo\b.*\n(?!.*\bbar\b)}mg'
```

With the standard Unix toolchest, you could use `sed`, though standard `sed` has no word boundary operator, so  you'd need clumsy workarounds:

```
sed -n '/^\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}foo\([^[:alnum:]_].*\)\{0,1\}$/ {
          $!N
          /\n\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}bar\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}.*$/!P
          D
        }'
```

Answer (score 1):

##### With `grep`:

(regex hardened with *word boundaries*)

```
grep -Pzo '(?m)\bfoo\b(?!.*\n.*\bbar\b)' file
foo
```

- `-P` is [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) mode
- `-z` is `NULL` `\0` delimited to enable parsing all lines as a string (`\0` is meant for *end of filenames*)
- `-o` is meant to display only the matching part

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?m)` | set flags for this block (with ^ and $ matching start and end of line) (case- sensitive) (with . not matching \n) (matching whitespace and # normally) |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `foo` | 'foo' |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `(?!` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is not: |
| `.*` | any character (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `.*` | any character (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `bar` | 'bar' |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

##### With [php](/questions/tagged/php) (I guess regex101 is based on `php` regex flavor `PCRE`):

```
php -r '$pattern = "1 foo 1 
foo 2
baz bar bap";
preg_match("/foo(?!.*\n.*bar)/m", $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);'
```

##### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

To print `foo`, use `echo $matches[0][0];`

Comment: Copied and pasted your grep command and it returned nothing but thanks for the informative response.

Comment: Try it again, post edited accordingly. Usually, the way to thanks is to vote up++

Answer (score 1):

As in life, in software it's much easier to take action based on what **has** happened in the past (i.e. data you've read) rather than based on what **will** happen in the future (i.e. data you haven't read yet).

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '(p ~ /foo/) && !/bar/{print p} {p=$0} END{if (p ~ /foo/) print p}' file
1 foo 1
```

Rather than trying to print the current line if it contains foo and the next one doesn't contain bar, that prints the previous line if it contains foo and the current one doesn't contain bar.